# Force install devDependencies to global with yarn or npm?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I use `eslint`, `gulp`, etc.. module global with :

```
yarn global add name_of_them
```

and almost my project use it with `devDependencies`, I have idea that just install in global and add it to `NODE_PATH`, some build script can call `require` it.

But sometime, I use some module is not installed, and I type: `yarn` to install it.
Some module call other module with path like: `../name_other_module`, it will break if I install one in local, one global.

Can I install module in `devDependencies` to my global path ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I recommend against going down that path. Install everything locally, and run the scripts either through `yarn ${cmd}`, e.g. `yarn gulp`; or add their usage to `.scripts` in the `package.json`. Those commands will also be looked up from the local project. The perceived benefit of sharing a dependency is not worth it.